# Mailing in box2d (iphone) application

Tags: cocos2d-iphone, screenshot, box2d-iphone

I am developing a box2d(iphone) application in xcode. Can any one suggest me a sample code on how to take a screenshot in a box2d project. I found the code for view based application but couldn't find it for a cocos/box2d. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This forum thread on the cocos2d-iphone website should give you what you need: http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/1722/page/2